# CGI script ignores shebang line

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, cgi, shebang

I am trying to make python work on Apache on Ubuntu.

When I tried to run a cgi-script, with custom installed libraries, it would not work, so I looked for a solution and I discovered, that it runs wrong version of python.

Even when I put `#!/usr/bin/python3` as the first line of the script and try to display version of python it uses by `print(sys.version)`, it still uses python 2.7.6. It even worked, when I completely deleted the shebang line.

I checked that the path `/usr/bin/python3` is the correct one and it even has 777 permission. It seems it just ignores the shebang line. Or is there any settings in Apache that "hardcodes" the version of the python it uses?

Comment: There are probably several ways to fix the problem. One way is to start with this test: Execute `which python` and see what it returns. If it returns something other than /usr/bin/python3, you *can* delete the soft link that is in /usr/bin `sudo rm /usr/bin/python` and then run `sudo ln -s -T /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`. *NOTE: This will change the default python path on the entire system!*.

Comment: @Ron: you are aware this will WRECK his O.S., don't you?

Comment: OK I tried that, but when I type `which python` after that, it still gives me `/usr/bin/python`. I typed it like this: `sudo ln -s -T /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now start a python interpreter in the command shell. And check the version that starts. It should look something like: *Python 3.x.y...* where x and y are the minor and step releases.

Comment: But to @jsbueno point: This is not a good permanent solution. You'll have to  track down the apache2 cgi configuration that is using the default /usr/bin/python reference and fix it there -- if that is what is required. So even though this will fix apache cgi, MANY OTHER THINGS COULD BREAK even in system admin tools that rely on python2.7 or another version.

Comment: Yes, in command shell it starts Python 3.4.3, but the CGI script still shows Python 2.7.6

Comment: And do you have any idea how to track that configuration down? For example which files to check etc.